# Separate versions in changelog svn->xml->xsit->html

Tags: xml, svn, logging, ant

Setting:

The `build.xml` used when my team triggers a new version (via ant) contains a section in which Subversion is asked to create a `changelog.xml` files from Today to `build.lastrelease`. From this `changelog.xml` file, a html version is created via xslt.The result is one long `changelog` without any chance of telling where a version ends and where the next one starts.

Goal:

Either introduce separating lines between each version (if possible also note the version) or creating a separate `changelog` for each version.

Approaches:

1. I thought about using a loop to write VersionX to VersionX-1, but the log entries don't display information about their version. (only date and time)
2. However, the version folders do. Though when I create a logfile for a single Version, I'll always end up with selectedVersion -> firstVersion.
3. I know how to separate by date though, so I could filter the log entries using the Daterange in the svn command. However, I have no idea how to access the Date information displayed in the Windows Explorer.

I read the parts of "Version Control with Subversion" that seemed helpful and read various forum posts and blog entries about svn, xml, xslt and ant.

Comment: I would suggest that you start by looking at the XSLT that's used to generate the current changelog. You should be able to segregate each revision with a line, the revision number and timestamp from the output of svn log --xml and the correct XSLT - I do this today.

Comment: Would have to talk to my boss if we can include the revision number in the log file, thanks for the hint

Comment: The revision number is *already* in the Subversion log. You stated that part of your goal is "if possible also note the version" - so go forth and do it!

Comment: That's true, but the revision number is not the same as the version number.
Is it possible to include the folder in the log file?

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm talking about the subfolders of the tags, trunk and releases folders.

Comment: Without seeing your actual directory structure and what a "version number" is in your environment, one can only guess. You would have to parse the paths in the output of svn log, or retrieve the log separately for each version's tag.

Comment: softwarename/...  

.../branches       

.../releases

.../tags  

.../trunk  


/tags...  

.../1.1.2r  

.../1.2.0b etc.  

same for /releases  

though I just noticed that the trunk folder is not layed out like this...  

The only thing I can think of is somehow getting the Date info of the /trunk and /releases subfolders, make a loop in ant, forward the dates to the svn command and thus create the desired result.  

But I have no idea weather or not this is possible, I doubt it.  
  
Thank you for the effort though.